# Flutter inject css before the page loaded with InAppWebView plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I injected css into an InAppWebView component in Flutter, what hides content on a page but the content appears for a bit.
I tried contentBlockers in options to block the css selector and injecting css in the events of onLoadStart, onLoadStop, onWebViewCreated and onProgressChanged but I couldn't solve the flickering issue.

How can I inject the css before the page appears on the screen without content flickering?

Answer (score 3):

You could inject the CSS in the `onPageCommit` callback.

Here's a sample:

```dart
InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse("https://google.com"),
        ),
        onPageCommitVisible: (controller, url) {
          controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
              var style = document.createElement('style');
              style.innerHTML = "img{ display: none; }";
              document.head.appendChild(style);
          """);
        },
      )
```

This hides the `img` element from "https://google.com".